# SQL Query - Filtering results from multiple matches

Tags: mysql, sql

The below SQL searches for objects that are linked to the following IDs (0,3000042000000,1000019007037) at certain snapshot numbers (snapnum = (63, 48, 27)). Objects are linked by

```
PROG.galaxyId between DES.galaxyId AND DES.lastprogenitorId
```

This SQL query (below) returns **every** object that meets these criteria.

```
SELECT DES.galaxyId, PROG.galaxyId, PROG.stellarMass, PROG.snapnum 
FROM dbase PROG, dbase DES 
WHERE DES.galaxyId in (0,3000042000000,1000019007037) 
AND PROG.galaxyId between DES.galaxyId AND DES.lastprogenitorId 
AND PROG.snapnum in (63, 48, 27) 
ORDER BY PROG.snapnum DESC
```

However, I don't want **every** result. For every DES.galaxyId specified in (0,3000042000000,1000019007037) I want one result (if there is one) returned at each snapnum in (63, 48, 27). This result must be the most massive, i.e. the result with the largest PROG.stellarMass.

Can anyone suggest appropriate modifications to enable this? Thank you.

*Caveats: Unable to use LIMIT*

Comment: "For every galaxyId specified ..." which GalaxyId? PROG or DES? They seem like they're different

Comment: select all in a sub query and limit it in the outer query.. in the outer query do your filter on the des.galaxyid.. that should work

Comment: @Scott - Specified DES. Apologies.

Comment: @JohnRuddell - Could you provide an example if possible? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Carl M, I'm concerned about the join between DES and PROG.  Not knowing the specifics of the data, the SQL itself allows for duplicate PROG data since there could potentially be overlap in different DES.galaxyId-DES.lastprogenitorId ranges.  John's solution is the correct one - it would require you to calculate the largest stellarMass for each DES.galaxyId/PROG.snapnum combination and then look up a PROG.galaxyId that matches it.  Also not knowing your data, this could result in multiple PROG.galaxyIds too, if more than one PROG.galaxyId can have the same stellarMass.

Comment: @Scott - The stellarMass quantity is not unique, so that wouldn't be the best way to do it. If I understood you correctly. This query above returns the info I want plus information I don't need, but I just need to filter it somehow.

Comment: @CarlM, Some sample data might help, both raw and expected results. Part of the issue in knowing if we got the right query is making sure the data lines up. Part of the issue I'm having is your join on the BETWEEN condition - without knowing some of the data set, this may produce artifact rows that those unfamiliar with the domain would not know are wrong. So, the question is, what's the purpose of your use of BETWEEN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carl, I'm making some big assumptions here, but this might give you a visual on what John suggested in his comment.

```
SELECT MsM.galaxyId, min(PROG.galaxyID) AS PROGgalaxyID, MsM.maxStellarMass, MsM.snapnum
FROM (SELECT DES.galaxyId, PROG.snapnum, DES.lastprogenitorId, max(PROG.stellarMass) AS maxStellarMass
FROM dbase PROG, dbase DES
WHERE DES.galaxyId in (0,3000042000000,1000019007037) 
    AND PROG.galaxyId between DES.galaxyId AND DES.lastprogenitorId 
    AND PROG.snapnum in (63, 48, 27) 
GROUP BY DES.galaxyId, PROG.snapnum, DES.lastprogenitorId) AS MsM
JOIN dbase PROG on PROG.galaxyId between MsM.galaxyId AND MsM.lastprogenitorId and  PROG.snapnum=Msm.snapnum and PROG.stellarMass=MsM.maxStellarMass
GROUP BY MsM.galaxyId, MsM.maxStellarMass, MsM.snapnum
```

Assumptions:

- There is one PROG.galaxyID between each DES.galaxyId and DES.lastprogenitorId
- Each PROG.galaxyID has a unique stellarMass that is not shared by any other PROG.galaxyId

Comment: If you want to instead return *any* galaxyId that has the Max(stellarMass) (could be more than 1) then remove the max function and group by statement from the subquery

Comment: Cheers. The first assumption is indeed correct. The second is not. How come you're minimising PROG.galaxyId? I wouldn't have thought this would be required for what I want.

Comment: That was to output only a single PROG.galaxyId in the event that there were multiple matches.  If you want to show all of them, you can remove that function.  Your original question seemed to say you wanted only 9 results (3x3)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that's correct. Is there a missing variable in the first line you've posted there? Selecting 2 things as 3 things?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you

Comment: This is my inexperience showing! In that SQL, the top line is selecting 2 things (MsM.galaxyId, min(PROG.galaxyID)) but as 3 things (PROGgalaxyID, MsM.maxStellarMass, MsM.snapnum). Is that right?

Comment: Ah, no the first line is selecting 4 things, mirroring your example in the original question.  1 -> MsM.galaxyId; 2 -> min(PROG.galaxyID) which I'm renaming "PROGgalaxyID" for output purposes.  3 -> MsM.maxStellarMass; 4 -> MsM.snapnum.  Use commas as your delimiters and you'll see them.  Note that MsM refers to the results of the subquery.  "AS" renames things.  Example: Carrie Fisher AS Leia Organa

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. So I'm running the query and it has a problem "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." I can't, for the life of me, find where the problem is. It all seems perfectly legal.

Comment: Oops - the min() function didn't belong in the group by statement.  And you can't have AS in group by.  I fixed it in my answer

Comment: It throws up this error: "Column 'dbase.lastProgenitorId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Fixed again - this is saying lastProgenitorId should have been in the subquery's group by clause

Comment: Huzzah. This seems to produce the desired results. I know I didn't make it easy, so thank you.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Feel free to upvote and/or mark it as your answser

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DES.galaxyId, PROG.galaxyId, PROG.stellarMass, PROG.snapnum 
FROM dbase PROG, dbase DES 
WHERE DES.galaxyId in (0,3000042000000,1000019007037) 
AND PROG.galaxyId between DES.galaxyId AND DES.lastprogenitorId 
AND PROG.snapnum in (63, 48, 27) 
ORDER BY PROG.StellerMass DESC, PROG.snapnum DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm unable to use LIMIT. It's a limitation of the service I'm using. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Jaaz, LIMIT 1 will only give a single record, not one record per galaxyId/snapnum.  This isn't what the OP is looking for anyway.

Comment: I'll edit the query, I had apparently missed that line. Are there any other major limitations of the service we should be aware of?

Comment: @JaazCole - Not that I'm aware of.